# getInstalledApplications returning null

Tags: java, android, package-managers

I am trying to retrieve a `list of apps that are installed` on the phone/emulator. I am using the following snippet to return the list of apps, however, it is returning `null`. Do I have to add some `permission in Android Manifest` or am I missing something else?

```
pManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> appList =pManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

if(appList == null)
   System.out.println("null");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: Can you post complete code that you are using for getting installed apps?

Comment: This is the complete code. This one statement is what used for getting list of installed apps.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are getting null and not any RuntimeException?

Comment: Stacktrace is pointing that it is NullPointerException which is caused by passing null appList to someother method . So it is not runtime exception

Comment: Can you post stack trace?