# Finding apk files of a package in Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

I have a list of installed apps with `installed_apps` and I know that system app apks are stored in `/system/apps/package_name` and every other installed app in `/data/apps/package_name`. But how can I find the correct apk file which is used to execute a chosen app with flutter? I want to choose an app and show the `path/to/apk` with flutter.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Apps are installed from APK files, but they are not started using it (an APK is nothing you can execute).

Comment: I want to get the apk for a vulnerability scanner

Comment: Simply list the installed applications: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18355178/150978 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/21405206/150978 and the app entries also contain the `sourceDir` where the APK(s) are stored.

Comment: Ok, I found a similar library for flutter `android_package_manager` which uses the same API.